# Long paths when we create a service reference against a WF4 web service

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation-4, service-reference

We are using TFS as CI tool and we are having problems with long paths. Most of it is because of the service reference that creates using a WF4 service. It autogenerates an activity with a very long path (namespace+servicereferencename+interface+operation).

Do you know if there is a way to control those activities path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you generate them, well other than using short names :-)

The generated activities are not very complex however and it is quite easy to just create you own custom activity with a Receice and SendReply to do the same.